# How does XMLserializer.serialize behave when it has to update a list item with an empty list

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xml-serialization

I had an xml error this morning, and when I went looking I found an xml that looked like this:

```
<root>   
  <list /> 
<root> var </item> 
<item> var </item> 
</list> 
</root>
```

This is obviously wrong.

The only line in code that could do this is the following:

```
XmlSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, thisObject);
```

I suspect that it was trying to update the `<list><item>var</item></list>` with `<list />` and then got stuck on the first element because it immidiately closed it.

Does anyone know how the serialize function should behave in this example?

EDIT: I wrote some code to recreate the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace XMLserializetest
{

    public class sample
    {
        public DateTime LastRun { get; set; }
        public List<int> intlist { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string FileName = "c:\\temp\\list.xml";
            var file = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            try
            {
                var test = new sample();
                test.LastRun = DateTime.Now;
                test.intlist = new List<int>();
/*Comment this line and run again, then look at the xml*/                    
test.intlist.Add(1); test.intlist.Add(2); test.intlist.Add(3); test.intlist.Add(4); 

                var x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(test.GetType());
                x.Serialize(file, test);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var a = e;
            }
            finally
            {
                file.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a StreamWriter, so that the stream knows he doesn't need to append:

```
var file = new StreamWriter(FileName);
```

For this example you should then first check if the file exists before writing.

Answer (score 0):

I've added this line before loading the stream:

```
File.WriteAllText(FileName, string.Empty);
```

This empties the file, and thus, there is no confusion in the serialize method and all goes well.

Comment: I won't except my own answer for a while. I'm confident there must be a cleaner solution to this.

Comment: `FileMode.Create`, maybe?